# What's a generic noun for referring to the bulk material of pure chemical elements?

Tags: nouns, terminology

What's a generic noun (single word or multi-word term) for referring to the bulk material of pure chemical elements?

I am talking about H<sub>2</sub>, O<sub>2</sub>, lead, diamond, graphene, etc, but not chemical elements, i.e. the atoms of hydrogen, lead, carbon, etc.

Just like "chemical compound" is an umbrella word for water, CO<sub>2</sub>, etc. etc., what is the umbrella word for substances that is composed of a pure chemical element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element)

> **Chemical element** is a pure chemical substance consisting of one type of atom.

In the above sentence the term is used for the bulk material, not only for the type of atom.

Comment: Yeah actually I tend to agree with this: I think that's exactly what "element" means. If you wanted to emphasize a specific bulk, I might combine them as "elemental mass".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for molecule.

OED:

> **molecule** *noun* The smallest unit (usually consisting of a group of atoms) into which a substance can be divided while still retaining the substance's chemical qualities.

A molecule of oxygen is O<sub>2</sub>, the same for chlorine, hydrogen, etc.

It can also refer to compounds like CO<sub>2</sub>, etc. But I don't think there is a word that excludes such substances.

Comment: I believe he's looking for a term for a bulk of a material... i.e. the opposite of a single molecule.

Comment: @chaiguy Yeah, I wasn't sure which part was more important, the O_2 or the bulk

Comment: Both are important. Bulk material of a pure element. Maybe it has to be "chemical elements" as Unreason suggested that Wikipedia defines so. Although i keep thinking "chemical element" is degenerate in referring to both the bulk material and the atom, depending on the context.

Comment: @Computist: There is no degeneracy. An *element* is always a substance, never an atom. An oxygen atom is not an element, it is an atom of the element oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

*Mass* is usually used for a bulk of a solid or liquid. *Volume* could be used for gas, or also liquid.

Comment: NO, I'm not talking about referring to the instance. What I really want is an umbrella word for the examples I gave. Just like chemical compound is an umbrella word for water, CO_2, etc. etc.

Comment: Ah I see. A word that specifically means a mass of a single-element...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word [**reagent**](http://www.reagents.com/products/reagents/grades.html) to indicate a high purity chemical.

(Note that the word reagent, in this context, is short for reagent-grade compound/substance. In other words, a reagent doesn't necessarily indicate a chemical that is intended for use in bringing about a chemical reaction.)